# Binding event handlers to dynamic markup..works for click.. not for hover

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am working on a project that uses handlebars to create dynamic content.
Here is an example http://jsbin.com/hahiv/2/edit

I am not sure why the click event works but the hover does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know the question was stupid. Realized the answer on my way home. Accepting answer because someone helped me. Crunchtime creates brainfreeze..thats what happened. Thanks a ton for whoever gave this question the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `hover` is not a valid event you can use. Try using `mouseover` (the mouse enters the element) or `mouseout` (the mouse leaves the element) instead. [Here's the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nataceka/1/edit?html,js,console,output), hope it helps

There are also `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, but seems they aren't fully supported yet. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events)'s a complete list of the events, which explains the differences between them. And as you can see, there's no `hover` there.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'hover' use 'mouseover'

```
    $('#tblContent').on('mouseover','td',function(event){
      console.log("hovered");
    });
```